# Ansi TStringList in Delphi XE for non-Unicode compatibility

Tags: delphi, unicode, migration, devexpress

I am trying to migrate DevExpress TdxDBGrid for Unicode applications and the lack of non-Unicode TStringList is the only obstacle for completing the migration. I have tried to use TAnsiStringList from JcLAnsiString (from Jedi/Jcl open source project) and while it works, it includes too many dependencies on Jedi/Jcl framework. Generally my plan is to use migrated TdxDBGrid for working with unicode data, but TAnsiStringList is required for internal actions - like storing bookmarks, selected rows and so on.

Is the more lightweight non-Unicode TStringList (with less dependencies)?

Comment: I cannot see what's wrong with `TStringList`. Why don't you use that? Beyond that, assuming you do have a real need, how hard can it be to take the code from `TStringList` and replace `string` with `AnsiString`? Surely you are up to that task.

Comment: Are you sure that if you migrate your application to Unicode Delphi that the `TdxDBGrid` will require an `AnsiString` string list ? I don't know why would its developers do that. IMHO it needs just `TStrings` abstract class and the whole component is *Unicode ready* and using an `AnsiString` string list would be even wrong. But it's all just my guess (and hope for a good design of that component).

Comment: The only application for ANSI version of `TStrings` is large volume of wittingly ANSI text stored in memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate, [`D2009 TStringlist ansistring`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1119920/576719).

Comment: @TomR Re-investigate your statement "TAnsiStringList is required for internal actions - like storing bookmarks, selected rows and so on" It probably is untrue. If you still think you need an ANSI stringlist, show us why so that we can show a workaround. If you move to Unicode, do it all the way, as did DevEx (their components don't need ANSI).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what functionality of TStringList you use, but you can try generic `TList<AnsiString>` instead of `TStringList` for your task. If the only reason to use AnsiString type instead of String is keeping internally some strings, maybe it will be enough.

Comment: I understand this question as that the `TdxDBGrid` uses internally a `TStringList`. If that is so, how would you persuade `TdxDBGrid` to use `TList<AnsiString>` instead of `TStringList` ? I still somehow feel that nothing is needed to be done for such migration.

Comment: @TLama: Hi tried to use TAnsiStringList, so he definitely has sourcecode and do changes there. If internally it is used only like storage of strings, then it will be enough to replace TStringList to something else. If he already changed it to TAnsiStringList from JEDI, then he can try to define TAnsiStringList=List<String> without JEDI (maybe he will need to add some additional methods, but it is better then building it from the ground).

Comment: If that component uses internally `string` as elementary type (which was mapped to `AnsiString` on Delphi 2009 below, and `UnicodeString` above) and it uses common `TStringList` class (which has the same intenal mapping as `string` type), there's no need to do anything. In such case it would be even worse because if there is internally `string` type used and you force string lists to be ANSI, you will lose Unicode on them.

Comment: @TLama: We don't know details, but task is there, it means it doesn't work with new string type for some reason, isn't it ? I hope author of the task could not spend time for replacement if it can be just recompiled. :)

Comment: @Andrei It would be astounding if an ANSI string list was needed. The asker is surely trying to do something wrong. In my experience, it is very common for people to ask the wrong question.

Comment: @Andrei, If that component uses internally `string`, `Char` and `PChar` elementary types, those string lists are of common `TStringList` type and there are no explicit typecasts to ANSI strings (like for instance field value typecasts), no explicit calls to ANSI versions of certain functions (like Windows API), you don't need to do anything at all. I know the question asks for something else, but I'm going little bit deeper thinking that there's no need to change anything for migration of that component. [sorry for my human mindset :-)]